# Edit profile in mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

In mobile, if I want to edit my profile, I have to choose *full site* at bottom, and then only I can edit my profile. *Full site* requires zooming and irritate to see in mobile device.
So consider adding **Edit profile** in mobile version

Comment: I guess the rationale is that editing your profile happens so rarely, it's ok to expect users to use a desktop device to do it and save the development cost of implementing it in the mobile version. But it's certainly a valid feature request.

Comment: I actually looked for my Flair